# Error when setting value to null using Redshift ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, amazon-redshift

I recently switched form using a Postgres driver to the Amazon Redshift ODBC driver to access my Redshift datastore.

I have one C# process that started throwing errors and I narrowed it down to the following:

```
var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
var command = new OdbcCommand("update test set deleted = ? where status = ?", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", null);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "to_delete");
var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

The error I am getting is "ERROR [HY000] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState HY000] Default parameter is not supported."

The same code worked with previous driver. It seems the Redshift driver does not allow setting nulls using "= null".

How can I set a db field value to null using this driver?

Comment: Just a guess, but don't you want to pass the string "null" to the parameter, not an actual null value? Possibly the driver is complaining because you have not supplied a value for the parameter.

Comment: No. I don't want any value in the field. It's a nullable field and having a string of Null is not the same as a null value.

Comment: What you are doing is building a string that should evaluate to a valid SQL statement. You're trying to pass a null value into something that is expecting a string, try passing the string value "null" to the parameter, that should build the correct SQL statement i.e. you want the derived SQL statement to start "update test set deleted = null..." - in this context null is a _string_ until the Redshift SQL interpreter executes the SQL command.